# How to find nearest Lat/Lon to the given Lat/Lon from set of Lat/Lon values?

Tags: c++

I have a set of lat/lon values and gps lat/lon value. I want to find nearest lat/lon value to the gps point from that lat/lon set.

Is there any some formula or some other way so that i could implement that in my c++ program.

Comment: I don't think there is any single magic formula for this. You should first understand the problem and be aware that your angular units should be first converted to linear units before finding the nearest point. This webpage might help you gain some clues: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find nearest Lat/Lon you should calculate distance of each point(Lat/Lon) to the reference point (GPS Lat/Lon) and store all distance values in an array sort them to get closest value or reverse to get farthest. I hope it will help.

**Sample code to calculate distance**

```
#include <math.h>

#define pi 3.14159265358979323846

double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
  double theta, dist;
  theta = lon1 - lon2;
  dist = sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  switch(unit) {
    case 'M':
      break;
    case 'K':
      dist = dist * 1.609344;
      break;
    case 'N':
      dist = dist * 0.8684;
      break;
  }
  return (dist);
}

/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
/*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/
/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * pi / 180);
}

/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
/*::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :*/
/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180 / pi);
}</math.h>
```